# Java Persistence Many to Many relationship with self

Tags: java, database, annotations, many-to-many, persistence

I have a user class, users should have a list of friends. Friends are also users so every user should have many friends and obviously each of those friends(users) also have many friends(users).

So a many-to-many relationship of users is what I've assumed so far. This is currently the code I have been using (with hibernation JPA annotations)

Here is my MyUser code:

```
@Entity
public class MyUser {

@Id
private String username;
private String userPassword;

@ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
  name="USR_USR",
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USR1_ID", referencedColumnName="USERNAME")},
  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USR2_ID", referencedColumnName="USERNAME")})
private List<MyUser> friends = new ArrayList<MyUser>();

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setFriends(List<MyUser> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

public List<MyUser> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}
```

I'm trying to create a second table by joining the USERNAME column with itself (which doesn't really sound right to me I'll be honest.)

So I'm trying to create a relationship in my database where each MyUser can have many MyUser's.

I'm pretty stuck with this so some help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing your database schema to something like this:

```
MyUser(id, ....);
Friends(id1, id2);
```

Where MyUser.id is the primary key of MyUser, and Friends id1 and id2 are foreign keys to MyUser.id.

This is a pretty common pattern that will give you less problems in the future, and is a bit more maintainable. User A (w/ ID 1) is friends with User B (w/ ID 2) if there is a tuple in the Friends database (1, 2).

Hope that helps,